# How to convert synchronous method to asynchronous without changing it's signature

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, synchronous

I have a large scale C# solution with 40-ish modules.

I'm trying to convert a service used solution-wide from synchronous to asynchronous.

the problem is I can't find a way to do so without changing the signature of the method.

I've tried wrapping said asynchronous desired operation with Task but that requires changing the method signature.

I've tried changing the caller to block itself while the method is operating but that screwed my system pretty good because it's a very long calling-chain and changing each of the members in the chain to block itself is a serious issue.

```
public SomeClass Foo()
{
// Synchronous Code
}
```

Turn this into:

```
public SomeClass Foo()
{
//Asynchronous code
}
```

whilst all callers stay the same

```
public void DifferentModule()
{
 var class = Foo();
}
```

Comment: You **must** change the signature because you also call them in a different way. Otherwise they would not be async methods.

Answer (score 4):

Any implementation that fundamentally changes something from sync to async is going to involve a signature change. Any other approach is simply not going to work well. Fundamentally: async and sync *demand* different APIs, which means: different signatures. This is unavoidable, and frankly "How to convert synchronous method to asynchronous without changing it's signature?" is an unsolvable problem (and more probably: the wrong question). I'm sorry if it seems like I'm not answering the question there, but... sometimes the answer is "you can't, and anyone who says you can is tempting you down a very bad path".

---

In the `async`/`Task<T>` sense, the most common way to do this without breaking compatibility is to add a new / separate method, so you have

```
SomeReturnType Foo();
```

and

```
Task<SomeReturnType> FooAsync(); // or ValueTask<T> if often actually synchoronous
```

nothing that `Foo` and `FooAsync` here probably have *similar but different implementations* - one designed to exploit async, one that works purely synchronously. It is *not* a good idea to spoof one by calling the other - both "sync over async" (the synchronous version calling the async version) and "async over sync" (the async version calling the sync version) are anti-patterns, and should be avoided (the first is much more harmful than the second).

---

If you *really* don't want to do this, you could also do things like adding a `FooCompleted` callback event (or similar), but : this is still fundamentally a signature change, and the caller will still have to use the API differently. By the time you've done that - you might as well have made it easy for the consumer by adding the `Task<T>` API instead.

Answer (score 2):

The common pattern is to add an `Async` to the method name and wrap the return type in a `Task`. So:

```
public SomeClass Foo()
{
// Synchronous Code
}
```

becomes:

```
public Task<SomeClass> FooAsync()
{
// Asynchronous Code
}
```

You'll end up with two versions of the method, but it will allow you to gradually migrate your code over to the async approach, and it won't break the existing code whilst you're doing the migration.

Comment: Though please remember, Async calls need to be all the way till the entry point, that's the reliable way to benefit from the  Async code

Comment: @orenk - You'll have to change the code, since you're changing the return type

Comment: Yeah, but this can also be solved without having to change the whole call stack (at least afaik)

Answer (score 0):

If you desperately need to do this, it can be achieved by wrapping the `Synchronous` code that needs to become `Asynchronous` in a `Task` this can be done like this:

```
public SomeClass Foo()
{
    Task t = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Do stuff, code in here will run asynchronously
    }

    t.Wait();
    // or if you need a return value: var result = t.Wait();
    return someClass;
    // or return result
}
```

Code you write inside the `Task.Run(() => ...)` will run asynchronously

**Short explanation:** with `Task t = Task.Run(() => ...)` we start a new `Task`, the "weird" parameter is a Lambda expression, basically we're passing a anonymous Method into the `Run` method which will get executed by the `Task`
We then wait for the task to finish with `t.Wait();`. The `Wait` method can return a value, you can return a value from an anonymous method just like from any method, with the `return` keyword

**Note:** This can, but should not be done. See Sean's answer for more